# performing a Binary search with python

Tags: python, format

I'm writing a function that takes a string representing a country name as a parameter. This function first call your method answer from a previous question to get the list of countries, then do a binary search through the list and print the country's information if found.

this is the code for the first part which gets the list of countries:

```
def readCountries():
    open_file = open("countries.txt", 'r')
    new_list = []
    contents = open_file.readlines()
    for i in range(len(contents)):
        lsSplit = contents[i].split(",")
        new_list.append([lsSplit[0], float(lsSplit[1].strip()), int(lsSplit[2])])
    open_file.close()
    return new_list
```

this is the part i need help in:

```
new_list = readCountries()  
def printCountry(name):
    lo, hi = 0, len(new_list) - 1
    while lo <= hi:
        mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
        country = new_list[mid]
        test_name = country[0]
        if name > test_name:
            lo = mid + 1
        elif name < test_name:
            hi = mid - 1
        else:
            return country
    return countries[lo] if countries[lo][0] == name else None
```

The output i get from the second part is:

```
>>> printCountry("Canada")
['Canada', 9976140.0, 35295770]
```

how would I get it to look like this:

```
>>> printCountry("Canada")
Canada, Area: 9976140.0,    Population: 35295770
>>> printCountry("Winterfell")
I'm sorry, could not find Winterfell in the country list.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are saying you can figure out how to implement binary search but now to format output?

Comment: You mean some thing like this `return "%s, Area: %.1f, Population: %d"%(countries[lo][0], countries[lo][1], countries[lo][2]) if countries[lo][0] == name else "I'm sorry, could not find " + name + " in the country list."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
new_list = readCountries()  
def printCountry(name):
    lo, hi = 0, len(new_list) - 1
    while lo <= hi:
        mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
        country = new_list[mid]
        test_name = country[0]
        if name > test_name:
            lo = mid + 1
        elif name < test_name:
            hi = mid - 1
        else:
            return country[0] + ", Area: " + str(country[1]) + ",    Population: " + str(country[2])
    return "Sorry Can not find " + str(name)
```